# Show error message while hitting post method url directly in browser

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I want to show error message while hitting post method url directly using java springboot so I used try catch exception but it is not working, I am getting error message which i mentioned in this question, help or suggestion is appreciated.

I just required when we hit the localhost:8080/LoginProcess, url I need to show error404 html page.

**Controller Method**

```
@PostMapping("/LoginProcess")
    public String LoginProcess(@ModelAttribute("customer") Customer thecustomer,HttpSession session) {

        try {

            Customer result = customerservice.Login_service(thecustomer.getUserName(),thecustomer.getPassword());

            if(result==null)
            {
                return "login";
            }
            else if(result.getRole().equals("1"))
            {
                session.setAttribute("l_uname",result.getUserName() );
                session.setAttribute("l_pwd",result.getPassword() );
                return "admindash";
            }
            else
            {
                session.setAttribute("l_uname",result.getUserName() );
                session.setAttribute("l_pwd",result.getPassword() );
                return "customerdash";
            }

        }catch(Exception e) {
            return "err404";
        }

    }
```

**Error Message**

```
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sun Mar 03 16:18:46 IST 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
Request method 'GET' not supported
org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.handleNoMatch(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.lookupHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:422)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:368)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:65)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.getHandler(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:401)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandler(DispatcherServlet.java:1231)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try use , `@PostMapping(value = "/loginProcess")` or try use RequestMapping with method `@RequestMapping(value = "/loginProcess", method = RequestMethod.POST)`

Comment: no i am getting error --- This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sun Mar 03 17:15:22 IST 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available

Comment: Try using ajax to hit the url

Comment: from java not possible?

Comment: if you have html or jsp page use method = "POST" in form tag that's tell browser you have post method to do

Comment: if some hacker or user directly hit this url without the form page then i need to show custom error page now got my point?

Comment: if someone hit this url will take him to get method , try create another method @GetMapping("/LoginProcess") and return error page and hit it from browser

Comment: Oh! ok ok Thanks a lot, then I will do that

Answer (score 2):

I got the resolution by creating the same duplicate method with @GetMapping and it works fine. now it redirect to my custom error page. thanks to yali who gave me idea through comments.

```
@GetMapping("/LoginProcess")
    public String LoginProcess() {

        return "err404";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

try `@ControllerAdvice`and`ExceptionHandler`

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class DemoControllerAdvice {

    @ExceptionHandler(HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleIOException(HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException ex) {
        // prepare responseEntity
        return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not send http post request from browser,so I'll suggest you to use post man tools to test.

Comment: I am not creating rest api, what my question is if i directly hit the url http://localhost:8080/LoginProcess I need to show custom error that is my requirement not springboot default error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether Spring has provided any implementation on it. But you can handle it by writing your own intercepter.intercepter will execute before hitting to controller so you can check http methods type forward it to error jsp

Comment: I am a beginner so could you give me the interceptor code please